# jquery ui - draggable: onDrag - need to be able to update the css of the draggable...cant :(

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I am trying to update the position of the draggable while you drag it.... but as far as I can tell the positioning gets updated from jquery ui after the code I put in the `drag` function (so it is overriding my css) I can't even get the thing to change background colour!

Im actually trying to fix something when dragging a div and scrolling in the container with `overflow:auto;` .... incase you were wondering why I am trying to update the position.

```
$(".editable").draggable
({
    grid: [24, 86],
    drag: function(event, ui)
    {
        $('.editable').css({left: '100px'});

        // so im guessing jquery ui is updating the position after this?

    }
});
```

so....any ideas anyone?

I basically need to be able to update the position of the draggable after jquery ui updates the position...but while you are still actually dragging...I hope that makes sense :/

Thanks in advance, any input would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`drag` alone won't solve your problem, you need to use a `drag event listener`, on creation you only define the callback for the drag event, apply these changes:

```
$(".editable").draggable
({
  grid: [24, 86],
  drag: function(event, ui) {} //changed
});

//event listener
$( ".editable" ).on( "drag", function( event, ui ) {
  ui.position.left = 100; //check here
} );
```

Note my comment `check here`, I wasn't quite sure if you wanted to add `100px` to the `left` or define it `100px`, currently the code defines it to `100px`

Comment: awesome!! thanks very much G.Mendes! :)

...btw just incase people see this and can't get it to work...I had to change the "100px" to an integer (just 100)..apart from that it worked great!